# Writing a list to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I am trying to do the following:

For each entry in Col A, if that entry recurs in the same Col A, then add together all of its values in Col E.

Then, write only that (added) values from Col E into another excel sheet. Each Col A entry should have all the Col E values corresponding to it.

However, I can create that output sheet for the last row only.

[image: Source excel sheet]

Here is the code that I've written,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from xlrd import open_workbook
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = open_workbook('/Users/dem/Documents/test.xlsx')
wk = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(wk.nrows):
    a = str(wk.cell(i,0).value)    
    b = []
    e = []

    for j in range(wk.nrows):
        c = str(wk.cell(j,0).value)
        d = str(wk.cell(j,4).value)
        if a == c:
            b.append(d)
    print b
    e.append(b)

book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')

n = 0
for n, item in enumerate(e):
    sheet1.write(n,0,item)
    n +=1

book.save('/Users/dem/Documents/res.xls')
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Erred[image] resulting sheet(mine):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in the code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from xlrd import open_workbook
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from xlwt import Workbook
import copy

wb = open_workbook('C:\\Temp\\test.xls')
wk = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# you need to put e=[] outside the loop in case they are reset to empty list every loop
# e is used to store final result
e = []
# f is used to store value in Col A which means we only record value once
f = []

for i in range(wk.nrows):

    b = []
    temp = None

    a = str(wk.cell(i,0).value)    

    #here we only record value once
    if a in f:
        continue

    #here you should start from i+1 to avoid double counting
    for j in range(i+1, wk.nrows):
        c = str(wk.cell(j,0).value)

        if a == c:
            # you can put operations here in order to make sure they are executed only when needed

            d = str(wk.cell(j,4).value)
            k = str(wk.cell(i,4).value)

            f.append(a)

            # record all the value in Col E
            b.append(k)
            b.append(d)

            # you need to use deepcopy here in order to get accurate value
            temp = copy.deepcopy(b)

    # in your case, row 5 has no duplication, temp for row 5 will be none, we need to avoid adding none to final result 
    if temp:
        e.append(temp)

book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')

n = 0
for n, item in enumerate(e):
    sheet1.write(n,0,item)
    # you don't need n+=1 here, since n will increase itself

book.save('C:\\Temp\\res.xls')
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look forward to use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) with `dialect='excel'` There is an example in this documentation on usage. I think this is just the simplest way to work with excel if you don't need huge functionality like in your case.